# How to set the value of a model field by performing an equation between other model fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to set the value of a model field by performing an equation between other model fields. Here's my model:

```
class Current(models.Model):
    time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_score = models.ForeignKey(PostScore, blank=True, null=True)
    comment_score = models.ForeignKey(CommentScore, blank=True, null=True)
```

Say I want to create a new field called `rate`, which is calculated by:

```
(post_score + comment_score) / time
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need a field for this? Why don't you calculate it when you show it?

Comment: True just realised I can probably do it in my views.

Comment: Why doing it in the view ? You can make it a method of your model... And that's really where it belongs actually.

Comment: Good point a model function is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

**models.py**

```
class Current(models.Model):
    ....

    def get_current_rate(self):
        return (self.post_score + self.comment_score) / self.time
```

In **views.py**:

```
from mymodels import Current

def someview():
    ....
    rate = Current.get_current_rate()
```